# Getting an app on an emulator on android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using android studio and I have the app I am working on open. When I run the emulator, the app does not show up and I don't know where to find it to get it on the screen.

Comment: Did you try bringing up the menu and looking for the app just like on a normal phone? Emulators run very slowly though... You should try run it on an actual device if you could get one!

Answer (score 0):

If the the emulator is running and its android UI is already shown on your screen, just click "run app" in the Android Studio menu, and choose "Emulator" on the following dialog to run your app. Your app will be installed and run on the emulator automatically.

Comment: I hit run app and the emulator comes up but just with the regular screen and I can't find it anywhere on the phone